# Bar plot without grouping variable

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

This seems like to simplest thing to do, but I have not been able to figure this out on R. For descriptive purposes, I want to create one bar graph that show the means and error plots of multiple questions/variables. My data is based on anonymous responses so there is no grouping variables.

Is there a way to do this on R? Below is an example of what my data looks like. I would like to plot mean and standard deviation of each variable next to each other in the same bar graph.

```
dat <- data.frame(satisfaction = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  engaged = c(2, 3, 4, 2),
                  relevant = c(4, 1, 3, 2),
                  recommend = c(4, 1, 3, 3))
```

Comment: If you can find the values you want to plot, you can plot them. As-is, the most we can do to answer your question is say "yes"---which isn't useful to anyone so we'll probably close your question. However, if you [make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061), sharing a little sample data - either simulated or via `dput()` so it's copy/pasteable, and describe the output that you want, someone will probably share some code to show you how to do it.

Comment: Please see the link I posted above about making reproducible examples and share your data in a friendly format as suggested - either simulated or via `dput()`. An image of data is next to useless.

Comment: Thank you Gregor. I added a simulated dataset in my original post. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Much better! I've nominated for reopening. On more clarifying question - your goal is to have the x-axis be the column (e.g., satisfaction, engaged...) and for each column category you want two bars, one for the mean and one for the standard deviation. Is this correct?

Comment: @gregor Great, thank you! That is correct. However, for each column, I would like one bar - the bar would represent the average, and a line through the bar to represent standard deviation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you could do is reshape the data into long format with `reshape2` (or `data.table` or `tidyr`) without specifying an id-variable and using all columns as measure variables. After that you can create a plot with for example `ggplot2`. Using:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# reshape into long format
dat2 <- melt(dat, measure.vars = 1:4)  # or just: melt(dat)

# create the plot
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'bar', fun.y = 'mean', width = 0.7, fill = 'grey') +
  stat_summary(geom = 'errorbar', width = 0.2, size = 1.5) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

gives:

[image]

---

**Update:** As @GavinSimpson pointed out in his answer: for visualizing means and standard errors, a barplot is not the best alternative. As an alternative you could also use `geom_pointrange`:

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'pointrange', fatten = 5, size = 1.2) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much! This was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I know you asked for a barplot, a dotplot of the data is an alternative visualisation that focuses on the means and standard errors. If the drawing of a bar all the way to 0 is not that informative, the dotplot is a good alternative.

Reusing the objects and code from @Procrastinatus Maximus' answer we have:

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'point', fun.y = 'mean', size = 2) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'errorbar', width = 0.2) +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  theme_bw()
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Completely true about the point of visualizing means and standard errors!

Comment: There's a "meme" going around on [twitter](https://twitter.com/chbergma/status/709361543767580672) as well as scientific literature [[1](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1002128)] about usage of barplots (and whiskers).